# Making a Tree view in Sencha ExtJs 6.0

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I'm trying to make a simple tree view based on this example in ExtJs 6.0 without any success. It throws this error in the console, and the screen shows up in blank.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRoot' of undefined

If someone can point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

These are my files:

Model

```
Ext.define('ADMINSEG.model.Opcion', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeModel',
alias : 'model.opcion',
fields: [
    {name: 'task',     type: 'string'},
    {name: 'user',     type: 'string'},
    {name: 'duration', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'done',     type: 'boolean'}
]
});
```

Store

```
Ext.define('ADMINSEG.store.MntOpciones', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    storeId: 'myStore',
    model: 'ADMINSEG.model.Opcion',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'treegrid.json'
    },
    folderSort: true
});
```

View

```
Ext.define('ADMINSEG.view.aplicacion.Opciones', {
    extend : 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    requires : ['Ext.data.*',
                'Ext.grid.*',
                'Ext.tree.*',
                'Ext.tip.*',
                'Ext.ux.CheckColumn',
                'ADMINSEG.store.MntOpciones'],

    title: 'Core Team Projects',
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    collapsible: true,
    useArrows: true,
    rootVisible: false,
    store: 'myStore',
    multiSelect: true,
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'treecolumn', //this is so we know which column will show the tree
        text: 'Task',
        width: 200,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'task',
        locked: true
    }]
});
```

Comment: Try to use store like this - store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('myStore'). To use a store like you did, then the store should be registered in the application - f.e. using stores config of Controller.

Answer (score -1):

Finally found it! The store in the view must be invoked like this

```
store: Ext.create('ADMINSEG.store.MntOpciones')
```

Comment: This is not true, and even bad practice. Just do what yorlin says in the comment on your OP. Get the controller used with the view, or the application controller and add the store `MntOpciones` to the `stores array`. This will tell the framework that the store exists. After that you can use `store: [storeId]` on your view where in your case storeId is `myStore`.

Comment: If you want a shared store, do as suggested in the comments above. If you want a unique store per view, create the store in the initComponent method and assign it to the tree view.